# Would painting the underside of plywood serve as a vapor barrier to protect the plywood from absorbing moisture?

Tags: repair

I will strip the 3/4"tk x 3" wd t/g kitchen flooring and replace it with 3/4" t/g plywood.
I will install solid vinyl planks (akin to laminate flooring) on top of the plywood.
The question: Would painting the underside of the plywood serve as a vapor barrier to 
protect the plywood from absorbing moisture? It will be on above ground 24" center floor joists. The floor is approx 2' above ground level and sits on pillars.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: are you experiencing moisture problems now?

Comment: the original flooring is in bad shape, there is no sub floor.
I will remove this flooring and install plywood sub floor.
I want to seal the plywood so that it does not absorb moisture from under the house. I have decided to coat the plywood with